# What should be used in Flux/Mono to join couple items

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

In JS promises you can use 
[Promise.join](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html)

But I couldn't find such solution for Flux/Mono. What is best practice when you deal with the different item then have to use them together later?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you want to combine them.
Sequentially? Use `Flux.concat` 
All in parallel? Use `Flux.zip`
If you expect only one result, `Mono.zipWith` might work for you.

Comment: am I right that If I have Flux with 2 items and another Flux with 3 items than zip will return 2 tuples and I lost the last item in second Flux.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good number of 'merging operators'
zip, concat, merge, combineLatest are the main three.

Zip allows you to combine streams, where the items will be grouped in a 1-to-1 relationship within the stream. That is why you lost the last element.

When you are not sure about how numerous each stream will be and how often it will feed events you can use concat (add the other stream on the end of the first one), merge (where items are placed on the final stream in order of appearence from both streams), or combine latest (to mutate the two last events of each stream into something else).

Your case sounds like a merge to me.

Comment: My typical flow is: create Category -> Create Item using this category -> create couple history items using this item -> return item

Comment: this actually sounds like something like this:
service.createItem().doOnNext({itemCreated -> historiyService.createItems.flatMap{}}) I know this is crude to write in comments, but it should do the trick if you are looking to create the history, and then asynchronously save it as a side effect.

Comment: Regarding doOnNext I got on my other question such comment "...You should never do heavy I/O operations in a doOn*** operator. Those are made for logging or light side-effects operations..." That's why I don't quite understand what is the best way of createItem #1 -> create Some other Items #2 #3 - > return #1

Comment: You should never do heavy operation on the same thread. If you delegate these operations to a different scheduler I don't see the problem. If I remember correctly flatmap takes a scheduler argument. You could also return the stream from createItem#1 put a decorator on it, which would perform the flatmap with history creation+ subscribe so that the operation is run, and return just the createItem#1

Answer (score 0):

After some changes, my code looks like this

```
public Mono<Item> createItem(final @NonNull String userName, String description, String[] tags,
                             @NonNull Flux<ImageDTO> photos) {
    val item = initItem(userName);
    item.setDescription(description);
    if (null != tags) {
        item.getTags().addAll(Arrays.asList(tags));
    }

    return photos.flatMap(photo -> imageService.storeImage(photo.getStream(), photo.getExt()))
        .reduce(item, (item1, photoIri) -> {
            item1.getPhotos().add(photoIri);
            return item1;
        })
        .flatMap(itemRepository::save)
        .flatMap(createdItem -> {
            val itemHistory = getHistoryForCreatedItem(userName, createdItem);
            return itemHistoryRepository.save(itemHistory).then(Mono.just(createdItem));
        });
}
```

Currently I don't like:

- .reduce(item, (item1, photoIri) ->
- .then(Mono.just(createdItem))

Comment: What don't you like about it? 
I'd recommend extracting the lambdas into methods so you can use method references.